# Setting safe insets for Android on NativeScript

Tags: android, nativescript

For iOS I am using `app.ios.window.safeAreaInsets` to discover the safe insets in NativeScript.

Similarly, I would like to discover the safe insets for Android phones, so I can properly handle Android devices that have a soft navigation for example or newer Android phones that have a notch as well (for example the OnePlus 6).

I see in the `tns-platform-declarations` that for SDK levels 20+ there is the class `android.view.WindowInsets` which has methods like `getSystemWindowInsetTop()` and `getSystemWindowInsetBottom()`, which seems to be exactly what I need.

I am struggling however to call those methods and was wondering whether anyone could advise on how to proceed.

So far I found that the `decorView` has a method `onApplyWindowInsets()`, but as far as I can see I already need to pass that one an instance of `android.view.WindowInsets` which as far as I can tell is what I am after.

This is what I have so far:

```
if (app.android && device.sdkVersion >= '20') {
  const window = app.android.startActivity.getWindow();
  const decorView = window.getDecorView();

  //decorView.onApplyWindowInsets();
}
```

Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 2):

This snippet works for me, at least for detecting the bigger height of a status bar with notch.

```
let androidStatusBarHeight = 0;

const context = application.android.context;
const metrics = new android.util.DisplayMetrics();
context.getSystemService(android.content.Context.WINDOW_SERVICE).getDefaultDisplay().getRealMetrics(metrics);
console.log(metrics.density);
const resourceId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
if(resourceId > 0) {
  console.log(context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId));
  androidStatusBarHeight = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId) / metrics.density;
} else {
  androidStatusBarHeight = 24;
}
return androidStatusBarHeight;
```

Comment: Hi Paul! Struggling with a deadline momentarily, so haven't tried it out yet but thanks a lot for your solution!!